# set logger level dynamically

Tags: java, logging

I need to set the logging level of my Pentaho Kettle Job dynamically.
Like the level to be set as INFO, ERROR etc. I need to get the level from property file

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
InputStream input = null;
input = new FileInputStream("D:\\config.properties");
prop.load(input);
System.out.println(prop.getProperty("logLevel"));
job.setLogLevel((LogLevel) prop.getProperty("logLevel"));
```

I cant set like this because **prop.getProperty** is string. It cannot be casted as LogLevel

How to fetch this level dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library you are using, but this can work generally:

```
LogLevel ll = null;
switch (prop.getProperty("logLevel")) {
    case "info" : ll = LogLevel.INFO; break;
    case "debug" : ll = LogLevel.DEBUG; break;
    case "warn" : ll = LogLevel.WARN; break;
    default : ll = LogLevel.ERROR; break;
}
job.setLogLevel(ll);
```

The implementation can be vary for different Log libraries.